# Multiple <url-pattern> in <filter-mapping> not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, filter, web.xml, url-pattern

I use several filter in my `web.xml` of my spring App. some of my filter has multiple `url-pattern` to act on these urls, likes below:

```
<filter>
    <display-name>AuditLogFilter</display-name>
    <filter-name>AuditLogFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.somePackages.log.AuditLogFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuditLogFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/portal/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/view/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/rest/**/front</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

But i found that the `AuditLogFilter` don't act on all of these `url-patterns`. any solution?

Comment: From what I can see the your filter mapping syntax is fine. In which url-patterns the filter does not work?

Comment: @periklis, thanks for your comment, I found my solution and post it as my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Finally resolve my problem By changing the order of `AuditLogFilter` to top of my filters in `web.xml`. In other words, I put `<filter>` and `<filter-mapping>` parts in above of my **filter** definitions instead of end of `web.xml` file.